# Joining similar data from two indexed arrays

Tags: php, arrays, merge, default-value

I have to combine two arrays into one in such manner: 'v' field from the 1st array should be saved as 'v1' field in a result array, identically named field from the 2nd array - as 'v2', but grouped WITH THE SAME 't' field. All 't' fields must be distinct and ordered.

For example:

```
$a1 = array(
  0 => array('v' => '13','t' => '2015-09-08 18:50:00'),
  1 => array('v' => '25','t' => '2015-09-08 19:00:00'),
  2 => array('v' => '34','t' => '2015-09-08 19:05:00'),
  3 => array('v' => '24','t' => '2015-09-08 19:10:00'));

$a2 = array(
  0 => array('v' => '10','t' => '2015-09-08 18:50:00'),
  1 => array('v' => '29','t' => '2015-09-08 18:55:00'),
  2 => array('v' => '17','t' => '2015-09-08 19:00:00'));

/* ... */

$result = array(
  0 => array('v1' => '13','v2' => '10','t' => '2015-09-08 18:50:00'),
  1 => array('v1' => null,'v2' => '29','t' => '2015-09-08 18:55:00'),
  2 => array('v1' => '25','v2' => '17','t' => '2015-09-08 19:00:00'),
  3 => array('v1' => '34','v2' => null,'t' => '2015-09-08 19:05:00'),
  4 => array('v1' => '24','v2' => null,'t' => '2015-09-08 19:10:00'));
```

Notice that 't' dates go in 5 min increment, but each array doesn't necessarily contains values for every interval (random gaps possible).

Arrays are big enough (>30,000). Could you help me to make an effective algorithm (less code)?

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php, not quite sure if this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty efficient:

```
$final = [];
$a1 = array_map(function($a) { return ['v1' => $a['v'], 't' => $a['t']] }, $a1);
$a2 = array_map(function($a) { return ['v2' => $a['v'], 't' => $a['t']] }, $a2);
$a = $a1 + $a2;
foreach($a as $el) {
    $timestamp = $el['t'];
    if (!isset($final[$timestamp])) {
        $final[$timestamp] = ['v1' => null, 'v2' => null];
    }
    $final[$timestamp] = array_merge($final[$timestamp], $el);
}
usort($final, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['t']) - strtotime($b['t']);
});
```

If you're on an older version of PHP you'll need to change any array declarations using `[]` to `array()`

Comment: Thank you, but i've found a small bug: `$a = $a1 + $a2` should be replaced with array_merge() - because both arrays have common keys, and that method of combining will collapse duplicates.

Comment: Even after fixing two typographical errors this answer is provably incorrect because it does not deliver the expected result. [Proof](https://3v4l.org/vVcVQ)  Furthermore, it makes three loops whereas only two are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are processing a relatively large data set, then scripting for performance/efficiency is a worthwhile pursuit.  Keep you time complexity to a minimum.  Iterate the two input arrays only once.  Use temporary first level keys to make finding related row fast and reliable. Sort the result array by the temporary keys if desirable, then remove the temporary keys with `array_values()` if desirable.

As a programmer judgment call, if you are happy to keep the datetime string as a first level key, then perhaps you can omit it from the row elements in the result array (because storing redundant data is wasteful of resources).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/HhF63))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($a1 as $row) {
    $result[$row['t']] = [
        'v1' => $row['v'],
        'v2' => null,
        't' => $row['t']
    ];
}
foreach ($a2 as $row) {
    if (isset($result[$row['t']])) {
        $result[$row['t']]['v2'] = $row['v'];
    } else {
        $result[$row['t']] = [
            'v1' => null,
            'v2' => $row['v'],
            't' => $row['t']
        ];
    }
}
ksort($result);
var_export(array_values($result));
```